# Facebook integration and event fetching in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi I am working in xcode 6.4.
I am trying to create an application which integrate with Facebook.I want to fetch the event details of the user. That is, I want `event_name`, `place`, `time`, number of friends going and their details. I found many answers for this problem here and I tried them. But I couldn't build the app with that much of information. Please give me a detailed solution for the same.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/events" 
     parameters:@{@"fields":cover,name,start_time,end_time"}  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
     if (!error) 
     { 
         NSLog(@"event_name%@",[result objectForKey:@"name"]);
         NSLog(@"start_time%@",[result objectForKey:@"start_time"]);
         NSLog(@"end_time%@",[result objectForKey:@"end_time"]);}
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", [errolocalizedDescription]);
     }
}];
```

Comment: I want the details of my friends who are going to that event

Comment: Fixed formatting, typos and grammer.